# Creating mask layer to clip raster correctly from shapefile in QGIS v3.16.0

Tags: qgis-3, rasterization, vector-layer

**Problem**:
To create a mask layer to use `clip raster by mask layer`. I am facing problems with correct creating the mask layer.

I use `processing.run('gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer', {'INPUT':f'{gen_path}/{output_tin_grid}','MASK':f'{PT_output_bounding_mask}','SOURCE_CRS':None,'TARGET_CRS':None,'NODATA':None,'ALPHA_BAND':False,'CROP_TO_CUTLINE':True,'KEEP_RESOLUTION':False,'SET_RESOLUTION':False,'X_RESOLUTION':None,'Y_RESOLUTION':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':0,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':f'{gen_path}/{PT_grid_clipped}'})` to execute this in a script.

The input for the mask layer `PT_output_bounding_mask` is generated as a result of the following steps:

Image-1 below,

[image: Shapefile (.shp) with latitude, longitude and depth]

shows the boundary of interest. The area inside the boundary is of interest.

I currently use `Vector Geometry`> `Minimum Bounding Geometry`, while selecting `Geometry Type` as `Convex Hull`. Image-2 below, represents the polygon which results from using `Minimum Bounding Geometry`. [image: Polygon from Minimum Bounding Geometry].

I use `processing.run('qgis:minimumboundinggeometry', {'INPUT':f'{PT_boundary_file}','FIELD':'','TYPE':3,'OUTPUT':f'{PT_output_bounding_mask}'})` to execute this in a script.

As evident from Image-2, there are several areas wherein the bounding geometry polygon goes beyond the shapefile's path.

**Objective**:
I wish to generate a polygon which 'exactly' fits the points/ path of the shapefile shown in Image-1 which might look closer to Image-3 below,

[image: 'Correct' mask for clipping raster]

Additional information:

- I am unable to SAGA and GRASS extensions on my QGIS.
- As mentioned above, I use the generated polygon to clip raster generated using the following lines, `processing.run('qgis:tininterpolation', {'INTERPOLATION_DATA':f'{input_fname}::~::0::~::2::~::0','METHOD':0,'EXTENT':'77.98013305664062,77.9990005493164,31.55585289001465,31.56477165222168 [EPSG:4326]','PIXEL_SIZE':2.5e-06,'OUTPUT':f'{gen_path}/{output_tin_full}'})`

Comment: Would the tool *Concave hull (alpha shapes)* give your desired polygon? Or if the points are ordered in a ring, you could try *Points to path* followed by *Lines to polygons*.

Comment: - Both #1 Concave hull (alpha shapes) and #2 Points to path + lines to polygon seem to work.
- However, #2 seems to follow the path more closely! 
Thank you very much!